# Changing a nomenclature's subgroup title?

Tags: nomenclature

I am writing my first document (master thesis) using LaTeX and I have a problem with the nomenclature. The style sheet I am using gives the instruction to add stuff to the nomenclature this way:

```
\nomenclature[g-pi]{$\pi$}{ $\simeq 3.14\ldots$}
```

"g" is the prefix for greek letter, and there is also "a" for roman letters and "x" for other symbols. I would like to change the title displayed in the nomenclature from "Other symbols" to "Physical constants". How can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example of code? See how to build a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)